# SonarQube issue with New FileReader

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

Below mentioned Code snippet gives Sonar comment with following squid rule: [squid:S1943](https://sonarqube.epk.ericsson.se/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1943)

```
  try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(**new
    FileReader**(properties.get(FILE_BASED_CONFIGURATION).toString())))
        {
             //some code
        }
 catch (IOException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            LOG.error("Exception while reading from File", e);
            //customerInfo.clear();
        }
```

**[SONAR] MAJOR: Remove this use of constructor "FileReader(String)"**

Answer (score 4):

this is due to the use of default system encoding for FileReader which is generally bad. You should use

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(properties.get(FILE_BASED_CONFIGURATION).toString())), encoding)))
    {
         //some code
    }
 catch (IOException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        LOG.error("Exception while reading from File", e);
        //customerInfo.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that you haven't specified an encoding for the file, which means that the file will be read with your system's default encoding.  This means that the behaviour of the code could vary from system to system.

You should explicitly state the file's encoding, for example,

```
new InputStreamReader(
   new FileInputStream(
     properties.get(FILE_BASED_CONFIGURATION).toString()), "UTF-8")
```

This reads the file with a `FileInputStream` (which reads bytes from a file), then wraps this in an `InputStreamReader` which converts those bytes to characters using the stated encoding.